# geth states eth_submitHashrate while mining with Claymore on Windows 10 with 2 GPU's

Tags: gpu, ethereum, go-ethereum, mining, geth

I am aiming on GPU-mining Ethereum on a Windows 10 PC with 2 Radeon RX590.

**geth** version is

**1.9.9-stable-01744997**

cmd call to start geth:

```
geth --rpc --syncmode "fast" --cache 4096 --etherbase [ADR] --datadir "[MyDataDir]" --mine --minerthreads 0
```

Blockchain is up to date and everything seems fine on the geth side.

**Used Miner** is

**Claymore's Dual GPU Miner - v15.0**

cmd to start miner:

```
EthDcrMiner64.exe -epool http://127.0.0.1:8545 -mode 1 -tt 75
```

Now the miner starts and seems to start mining. GPU's show they are doing massive work.
Once the miner is initiated it only permanently outputs something like this (plus every once in a while some GPU info):

```
ETH: 12/21/19-15:46:33 - New job from 127.0.0.1:8545
ETH - Total Speed: 21.345 Mh/s, Total Shares: 0, Rejected: 0, Time: 45:52
ETH: GPU0 10.665 Mh/s, GPU1 10.680 Mh/s
```

So this looks good.

In the geth console meanwhile I get this output:

```
INFO [12-21|15:46:35.446] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=74   mgas=9.921   elapsed=159.999ms mgasps=62.007  number=9141165 hash=05972d…032349 dirty=1019.58MiB
INFO [12-21|15:46:35.459] Commit new mining work                   number=9141166 sealhash=35129c…59de27 uncles=0 txs=0    gas=0       fees=0             elapsed=999.3µs
INFO [12-21|15:46:35.720] Commit new mining work                   number=9141166 sealhash=3788e2…df83fc uncles=0 txs=39   gas=9922304 fees=0.0347883012  elapsed=261.998ms
WARN [12-21|15:46:36.032] Served eth_submitHashrate                conn=127.0.0.1:54083 reqid=6 t=0s        err="the method eth_submitHashrate does not exist/is not available"
INFO [12-21|15:46:38.548] Commit new mining work                   number=9141166 sealhash=7451f4…69a431 uncles=0 txs=72   gas=9911680 fees=0.04369322037 elapsed=89.942ms
WARN [12-21|15:46:41.120] Served eth_submitHashrate                conn=127.0.0.1:54083 reqid=6 t=0s        err="the method eth_submitHashrate does not exist/is not available"
```

There is this warning/error message:

**err="the method eth_submitHashrate does not exist/is not available"**

But also it states **"Commit new mining work"**.

I am quite unsure now.
Do I mine or do I only waste electric power as the work is never commited?

Answer (score 0):

You have not connected to any `mining pools`, only to your own geth node, meaning that you are mining alone and competing against the **whole** world. When mining solo, you have no shares. You either mine a whole block or get nothing. It is extremely hard to mine all alone, thus it is advised to join a `mining pool`. Claymore-Dual-Miner (CDM) has a [list](https://github.com/Claymore-Dual/Claymore-Dual-Miner/wiki/ETH-Mining-Pools-List-(updated-2019)) of available mining pool alternatives.

Also, when mining solo with CDM, you can miss `mined` messages because in this mode, it uses HTTP protocol instead of the Stratum pool protocol. You can manually check your balance on [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/balancecheck-tool) at any time, though.

Comment: I am aware of the pool/solo situation and I am not saying I will stay solo mining forever. What I want to know though is IF I am actualy commiting any mining work atm in the situation as states in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use PhoenixMiner 5e with -rate 2 command. It will stop showing this error.

Comment: Please add the exact command to your answer to better clarify the issue.